# Script to toggle dropdown menu on hover isn't working for new dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a script which toggles the dropdown menus when a user hovers over the menu item, if the navbar is not collapsed. I tried to turn the `.navbar-brand` into a dropdown menu as well but it doesn't open on hover.

Why isn't this working?

This is the final working fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/galindbergh/jkkvk1v7/13/

This is the HTML I tried for my `navbar-brand` dropdown-menu that doesn't work properly.

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand dropdown" style="font-size: 14px;" data-toggle="dropdown">Brand Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the script that toggles the dropdown menus on hover

```js
$( '.dropdown' ).hover(function() {
    // you could also use this condition: $( window ).width() >= 768
    if ($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') === 'none' 
        && false === ('ontouchstart' in document)) {
        $( '.dropdown-toggle', this ).trigger( 'click' );
    }
}, function() {
    if ($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') === 'none'
        && false === ('ontouchstart' in document)) {
        $( '.dropdown-toggle', this ).trigger( 'click' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly structure the dropdown menu.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/0609nbp3/3/))

Change this...

```html
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand dropdown" style="font-size: 14px;" data-toggle="dropdown">Brand Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

To this...

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav col-xs-10 col-sm-12">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Brand Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now I want to change navbar collapse breakpoint using your script. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603494/change-the-navbar-collapse-breakpoint-by-using-the-script-for-the-drop-downs-on>

Answer (score 0):

You should create two different .navbar-brand elements and use the [bootstrap responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) to switch between the two. So something like:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand dropdown visible-md visible-lg">Brand Dropdown</a>
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand visible-xs visible-sm">Brand Normal</a>
```