# Change the navbar collapse breakpoint by using the script for the drop downs on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the navbar collapse breakpoint to 1000.  The script below is used to make all drop down menus in the navbar, including `navbar-brand`, drop down on hover.  After collapsing the `navbar-brand` drops down on click. It does exactly what I want it to do.

But now I want to also change the breakpoint for the navbar to collapse.

My question is how to use the condition in the comment: `// you could also use this condition: $( window ).width() >= 768`?

Could someone show me what the script looks like using this option? And if the 768 were changed to 1000 would this actually change the breakpoint for the navbar to collapse?

This is the script that toggles the drop downs on hover.

```
   $( '.dropdown' ).hover(function() {
// you could also use this condition: $( window ).width() >= 768
if ($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') === 'none' 
    && false === ('ontouchstart' in document)) {
    $( '.dropdown-toggle', this ).trigger( 'click' );
}
}, function() {
if ($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') === 'none'
    && false === ('ontouchstart' in document)) {
    $( '.dropdown-toggle', this ).trigger( 'click' );
}
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/galindbergh/jkkvk1v7/13/

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble understanding whats going on. Could you give ids to the elements you are referring to? I'm getting confused with what "Brand dropdown", "Brand link dropdown", and "Brand link area" are

Comment: Is the problem that the "Brand Dropdown" is not clickable when the window is resized?

Comment: I have made an update to you fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bahefmxy/1/). Can you see if this fixes your problem? If it does I will provide an answer with an explanation.

Comment: The question was edited for clarification.